# Fetch request with multipart data fails in firefox but not safari

Tags: javascript, firefox, vue.js, axios, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a simple file upload on a Vue app with the fetch api.

On the backend there's a simple `express.js` server listening on a route. I use a proxy for the backend on the Vue app.

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: "http://localhost:3344"
    }
}
```

vue app

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="sendFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="field">
      <input
        type="file"
        ref="files"
        class="file-input"
        @change="selectFiles"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <button class="button is-info">
        Send
      </button>
    </div>

  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Upload",

  data() {
    return {
      file: '',
    }
  },

  methods: {
    selectFiles() {
      this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
    },

    async sendFile() {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', this.file);

      try {
        await fetch('/upload', {
          method: 'post',
          body: formData,
        })
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

express app

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  res.json({received: 'yes'})
})

app.listen(3344, () => console.log("running on localhost:3344"))
```

I am using Firefox and Safari as my test browsers. I am running the apps on localhost, on MacOS 10.14. When I try sending the form with no file attached, it works as expected in both browsers. However, when I select a file and press send, the request fails in Firefox and I get a `TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."` error in the console. On the Vue app console, I get `Proxy error: Could not proxy request /upload from 0.0.0.0:8080 to http://localhost:3344.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (EPIPE).`

However, this does not happen on Safari, and it works as expected there.

I thought it might be the firefox version or some extensions, but I ran the nightly version with no addons and it still fails. I also tried using axios instead of fetch api, but same problem occured.

Answer (score 0):

strangely, this was fixed when I added a middleware on the express backend:

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();

const upload = multer({
    dest: './uploads/'
})

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  res.json({received: 'yes'})
})

app.listen(3344, () => console.log("running on localhost:3344"))
```

I still don't know why it doesn't work without the middleware in firefox, but in safari it does.